# неправильное деление long на double C++

Tags: c++, вывод, типы-данных, double, форматирование

Занимаюсь изучением C++. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: имеется переменная типа **long**, и мне нужно вывести ее, **поделив на 100.0, с сохранением дробной части**. Работает такое деление не со всеми числами . Например с следующими числами возникают вопросы: **1111101, 2222202 и т.д.** Приведу примеры выражений:

**1'111'111 / 100.0 == 11'111.1 //пропала единица**

**1'111'101 / 100.0 == 11'111 //отсутствует дробная часть**

**2'345'678 / 100.0 == 23'456.8 //пропала цифра семь**

Пожалуйста, помогите с решением данной проблемы и объясните причину такого поведения.

Добавил простой пример кода:

```
long num = 2'345'678;
std::cout << num / 100.0;
```

Comment: Покажите код. В том числе как выводите результат.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос, упростил, но суть остается та же

Comment: Смотрите результаты деления через отладчик. И еще читайте https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: подскажите, нет ли возможности выводить число в формате 23456.78 без использования флагов(`std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed | std::ios::showpoint)`)?

Comment: Если числа положительные, то просто отдельно печатайте целую часть и остаток функцией `printf("%ld.%02ld", num / 100, num % 100);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вывод на экран и само значение — это две большие разницы. По умолчанию выводится 6 значащих цифр. Этот параметр можно изменять, так что посмотрите на [вывод](https://ideone.com/Rv2qK6) вот такого фрагмента и убедитесь, что деление правильное :)

```
long num = 2'345'678;
std::cout << num / 100.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(12);
std::cout << num / 100.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
std::cout << num / 100.0 << std::endl;
```